# Using post form with TideSDK 1.3.1-beta and php

Tags: php, forms, tidesdk

I'm trying to use forms with post method to send data through pages, but after the submit the $_POST array is empty. Using get method instead, the $_GET array works.

Is there a fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use $_GET. TideSDK only uses method="get" and you dont even have to add the method to your form.

Comment: But what about long forms with more than 2048 characters? Then "post" should be used!